# android - ActionBar custom View without icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application a have an `ActionBar` with Tabs as navigation mode. I also use a custom `View` which adds another "line" to the `ActionBar`. Setup looks like:

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.ab);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "cs_regular.ttf");
    TextView title = (TextView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tvActionTitle);
    title.setTypeface(font);
```

**The problem:** I do not want an icon to be shown, but when I use `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);` my custom layout gets placed *BELOW* the Tabs and I need it to be above the Tabs in the `ActionBar`. Setting it to `true` places the layout as I need it, but shows the unnecessary icon.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by icon you mean the app icon. You can essentially make it invisible using styles. Add this to the style your Activity is using:

```
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
```